# excludeFilters of @ComponentScan does not work

Tags: java, spring

My application looks as follows:

AContext.java containing Beans that define the application. It has `@Configuration` and `@Import(RabbitMQContext.class)` to import a class defining Beans for `RabbitMQ` communication.

This works fine for dev/prod, but I have got an issue with related tests.

I have a TestContext.java defining the base context for the tests. It has

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {AContext.class,...})
```

Now, I don't want spring to instantiate the beans in RabbitMQContext.class because I don't have a RabbitMQ environment during tests.
So I thought, the easiest way would be to define excludeFilters in my TestContext.java to exclude classes having @EnableRabbit annotation:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {AContext.class,...},
excludeFilters=Filter(EnableRabbit.class))
```

But: it doesn't work as expected. When starting the test, I get errors because Spring tries to instantiate beans defined in RabbitMQContext.class.

I also read some similar questons on stackoverflow but found none that really helped, apart from the fact that non-working exclusion seems to be a problem that occurs more often.
Any hints?

Comment: Somehow a "non-update" from me: I solved the issue by introducing an explicit "test" profile in spring and annotating the class containing beans that must not be instantiated during tests with `@Profile{"!test"}`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=AContext.class)
```

Comment: If I do that, I get the following error:
`The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes`

If I add `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, the error persists. But it wouldn't make sense either because it already is used in the main application's class -- which is part of the classes named in the `@ComponentScan` annotation, by the way.